Synthesizing Acetamide from vinegar & ammonium solution
I'm making some acetamide from common household chemicals. It seems that one can simply mix vinegar & ammonium solution to obtain ammonium acetate. Then, according to Wikipedia, this ammonium acetate can be dehydrated to acetamide.
I'm not sure about the conditions of the dehydration. Since both of the starting chemicals are in aqueous solution the ammonium acetate is also in aqueous solution. Would simply boiling this ammonium acetate solution induce dehydration while there is still a lot of water?
By vague intuition, the water would push a reverse reaction turning whatever acetamide produced back to ammonium acetate. Although, I did check. There is no such reverse reaction or equilibrium like that with acetamide & water.
Maybe I should boil down the ammonium acetate solution until it crystalizes & then heat it ever so steadily (such as putting it in the oven) to drive off the last of the moisture until the crystals dehydrates?
So, in this specific instance, can dehydration happen in an aqueous solution or do I have to dry it first?

Acetamide has been prepared by distillation of ammonium acetate according to this Organic Syntheses procedure here. This procedure requires fractional distillation and takes considerable time. It is easier to buy acetamide.

Making acetamide requires caution, as the process involves high temperatures and potentially dangerous chemical reactions. Generally, you need to first obtain dry ammonium acetate, and then heat it under controlled conditions to dehydrate it to produce acetamide. However, if there is still water in the ammonium acetate, the dehydration reaction will not proceed easily, so it is necessary to evaporate the water first.
Directly heating ammonium acetate in an aqueous solution will not effectively produce acetamide, because the water will hinder the dehydration process. Evaporating the solution until it crystallizes, and then carefully heating the dry ammonium acetate, may give you the results you want.
However, it should be noted that this process is somewhat dangerous, especially without professional equipment and safety measures. There may be safety risks when trying it at home, so it is recommended that you do it under the guidance of a professional or use a safer method.
